# Vue: How do I render a dynamic component based on parent data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to render components based on the data that is passed to the parent page.

I am trying to use dynamic components to render the correct components based on the JSON object **@type** and grab the file name in the url *(without the extension)* of that object to then render the related component and pass the data from **Page.vue** to the rendered components.

If I set **:is="content.@type"** (as an example) then the output will render child components with the name **Image** & **Video** (removing everything in the URL expect for the filename) to render the correct component.

Is this possible or is there a better approach to this?

**Data:**

```
Content: object
  Content [Array]
    0:Object
      @id: "4effb045"
      @type: "http://url/images.json"
      _meta: Object
         name: "TestingImage"
    1:Object
      @id: "4effb045"
      @type: "http://url/video.json"
      _meta: Object
         name: "TestingVideo"
```

The data comes from a CMS and I'm not able to change the data.

**Page.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="page" v-if="content" class="page-wrapper container" :cid="this.$root.cidItem">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="page__items">

        <component v-for="content in content.content" :is="content.@type" :key="content.id"></component>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Images from "./components/Images"
  import Video from "./components/Video"
  import TextType from "./components/TextType"
  import Card from "./components/Card"

  export default {
    name: 'page',
    props: ['cid'],
    components: {
      Images,
      Video,
      TextType,
      Card
    },

    mounted () {
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        'url': this.$root.contentDeliveryUrl + this.$root.encodedQuery + this.$root.cidItem + this.$root.store
      }).then(result => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        this.content = amp.inlineContent(result.data)[0];
        console.log(this.content)
      }, error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
    },
    data () {
      return {
        content: []
      }
    }

  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import '../node_modules/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
  .container {
    max-width: 1366px;
  }
</style>
```

**Child Component Example
Images.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="images-wrapper container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="images">
          {{content.imageAltText}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Images'
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
  .images-wrapper {
    &__image {

    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What is the output of that though?

Comment: If i set :is="content._meta" (as an example) then the output will render child components with the name <TestingImage> & <TestingVideo> which doesn't match my component names and no data is passed. @type comes back with a invalid expression

Comment: Not sure I understand this line `...will render child components with the name...` What do you mean render with the name?

Comment: Edited to explain better.

Comment: Well, I believe you can do the file name extraction work in a method and use it on the `:is` directive.

Comment: Oh, i'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you could parse the URL in a method with [`v-bind:is`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) directive. You've probably figured it out by now, but here's my quick attempt.

```js
const content = {
  content: [{
    '@id': '4effb045',
    '@type': 'http://url/images.json',
    _meta: {
      name: 'TestingImage'
    }
  }, {
    '@id': '4effb046',
    '@type': 'http://url/videos.json',
    _meta: {
      name: 'TestingVideo'
    }
  }]
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      content
    }
  },

  methods: {
    extractName(content) {
      const [name] = /[^\/]*(?=\.\w+$)/.exec(content['@type']);

      return name;
    }
  },

  components: {
    Images: {
      template: '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x45" />'
    },

    Videos: {
      template: '<div>Some video component</div>'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component 
    v-for="content in content.content" 
    :is="extractName(content)" 
    :key="content['@id']">
  </component>
</div>
```

BTW, I would advise against using **HTML reserved words** as the component names (like in your case [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)) as it may fail to compile. See this [related issue](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/issues/149) on GitHub.

> [Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: Dialog

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. You can use the `is` directive to call your components. It is the best way.

As you asked, you need a method in your `Page.vue` to parse your `@type`.

```
methods: {
    parseType: function(type) {
        let typeParts = type.split("/")
        let filenameParts = typeParts[typeParts.length - 1].split('.')
        let parsedType = filenameParts[0]
        return parsedType 
    }
}
```

Now you can use this function in your template.

```
<component v-for="content in content.content" :is="parseType(content.@type)" :key="content.id"></component>
```